# Pull news from an RDF Feed using Ruby and Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, rdf

I would like to pull the `title`and `description` fields from the newsfeed  at `http://www.tagesschau.de/newsticker.rdf` to feed them to the Mac's Text-to-Speech engine.

My search for a nice Ruby Gem to do this has brought me to `Nokogiri`, but all examples that "pull something out" of a given XML seem to be centered around CSS somehow.

Does anyone have any idea how to save the `title`and `description` fields in an array?

Comment: I wonder, then, why I got two very concise, to-the-point answers to my "non-question".

Comment: Generally, the community likes to see see code and also evidence you've tried to solve the problem. If you had provided a sample snippet of the RSS feed, and then showed the resulting array you desired, it probably wouldn't have been closed. If you had some code, even if it had a `# not sure what to do here` part, it wouldn't have been closed. If you make any of these improvements, it will be more useful to future SO visitors and will likely be reopened.

Comment: Well, I understand. But it has been solved so there is not much value in adding my unfruitful attempts, is there? Thanks for making this clear, though. The cited "closed-because-of"-message below was a bit - unentertaining in comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [xpath](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-xpath) / [at_xpath](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_xpath) (the latter returns only one element):

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'pp'

entries = []
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('http://www.tagesschau.de/newsticker.rdf'))
doc.xpath('/rss/channel/item').each do |item|
  entries << [item.at_xpath('title').text(), item.at_xpath('description').text()]
end

pp entries
```

Answer (score 1):

For structured data like RSS, I recommend using a dedicated client as opposed to rolling your own parser with Nokogiri.

```
require 'simple-rss'
require 'open-uri'

rss = SimpleRSS.parse open('http://www.tagesschau.de/newsticker.rdf')
rss.entries.each do |entry|
  puts entry.title
  puts entry.description
end
```

Comment: Ahh, very nice indeed. I came across a couple of RSS parsers, but this one slipped through. Thank you!